# How can I get the pagination to work here?

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to coding, so I'm open to critique as well as help. I'm trying to apply pagination to my search results. I have returned the results I need, applied the limit and managed to get the pagination controls to present properly. However, when I select "next" or "previous" the pages have no results on. I'm sure there is something fundamentally wrong, but I just can't spot it.

```
?php
include_once("db_connex.php");
if (isset ($_POST ['search']))  {
    $searchq = $_POST ['search'];
    $count_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activejobs WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%$searchq%' OR region LIKE '%$searchq%' AND status= '1'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($count_query);
    // pagination starts here
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
      $page = pre_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET['page']);
    }
    else {
       $page = 1;
    }

    $perPage = 3;
    $lastPage = ceil($count / $perPage);

    if ($page < 1) {
       $page = 1;
    } 
    else if ($page > $lastPage) {
       $page = $lastPage;
    }

    $limit = "LIMIT " . ($page - 1) * $perPage. ", $perPage";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activejobs WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%$searchq%' OR region LIKE '%$searchq%' AND status= '1' ORDER BY jobid DESC $limit");
 }
 if ($lastPage != 1) {
    if ($page != $lastPage) {
       $next = $page + 1;
       $pagination .= '<a href="jobsearch.php?page='.$next.'">Next</a>';
    }

    if ($page != 1) {
       $prev = $page - 1;
       $pagination .= '<a href="jobsearch.php?page='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';
    }
 }

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $jobtitle = $row['jobtitle'];
        $region = $row['region'];
        $salary = $row['salary'];
        $jobdescription = $row ['jobdescription'];
        $joburl = $row ['joburl'];

        $output .= '<div id= "searchresults"><a href = "http://www.nursestation.co.uk/jobdetails.php?id=' . $jobid . '"><div id= "applybutton">Details</div></a><font id= "resultstitle">'.$jobtitle.'&nbsp-&nbsp'.$region.'&nbsp-&nbsp'.$salary.'</font><br>'.$jobdescription.'</div>';
 }

?>
```

Comment: The code is open to sql injection (serious security issue). Please switch from mysql_* to pdo or mysqli (resources are easily found by searching). For avoiding the sql injection, you could use prepared statements. Make sure you always sanitize user input

Comment: Thanks Ronni, changed to Mysqli. Much appreciated. Need to do some reading to understand the differences. (Added to the long list of reading to be done)

Comment: Well mysql_* is deprecated (check the php manual page, it has a big red box :) ). Have you var_dumped the query when you do not get the results as planned?

Answer (score 1):

This kinds of *if-else* hell:

```
// pagination starts here
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = pre_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET['page']);
}
else {
   $page = 1;
}
```

can be solved like this (default it at start):

```
// pagination starts here
$page = 1;
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = pre_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET['page']);
}
```

or even this (if you feel adventurous):

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? pre_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET['page']) : 1);
```

Making a lot of If-else is easy at start and hard later, so keep it simple by reducing when you have nothing to do. Making your code smaller in a step **closer** to any solution.

Also this is common:

```
...
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $jobtitle = $row['jobtitle'];
   $region = $row['region'];
...
```

Why assigning `$jobtitle` to `$row['jobtitle'];` ?
It doesnt make your code easier, it just adds more code and making you read harder.
Give `$row['X']` directly.

Also, as **@ojovirtual** stated you need to pass **"$search"** parameter everytime, otherwise your entire code block will be ignored (**"$search"** is not set)

Finally, when working with MySQL you need to check the values you feed your queries with,
in this example the `$searchq`. A malicious coder could make the `$searchq` look like a part of the query.
There is a simple fix for that:

Instead of plain:

```
$count_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activejobs WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%$searchq%' OR region LIKE '%$searchq%' AND status= '1'");
```

make it a habit doing this:

```
$searchq = mysql_real_escape_string($searchq);
$count_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activejobs WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%$searchq%' OR region LIKE '%$searchq%' AND status= '1'");
```

Not a universal solution but a starter before dive into new technologies as a starter.
This is a must for fields like *username, password* etc.

Finally, change from:

```
if (isset ($_POST ['search']))  {
    $searchq = $_POST ['search'];
```

to:

```
if (isset ($_GET['search']))  {
    $searchq = $_GET['search'];
```

Comment: The change from $_POST to $_GET , which you suggested in your last change suggestion, seems to break my page.

Comment: You're using an <A>nchor tag to send data to server. Anchor's data get back as `$_GET[]`, not `$_POST`. A broken page is quite vague.

Comment: Apologies on the vague nature of my comment. Turns out it was a syntax error on my part. Thanks, also, for the explanation. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `search` again in your `next` and `previuos` buttons. A quick fix would be:

Change `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST`:

```
if (isset ($_REQUEST ['search']))  ...
```

Add the search to your `next` and `previous`buttons:

```
$pagination.= '<a href="jobsearch.php?search='.urlencode($_REQUEST["search"]).'&page='.$next.'">Next</a>';
```

Same with the `previous` button.

As someone stated, you should do some input sanitation before any database query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Your option produces this url: http://mywebsite.co.uk/jobsearch.php?search=Nurse&page=2,  As expected. However, I receive a blank page on clicking next.